# Oriented Cobordism Rings

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Hey everybody!
I was wondering if anybody had available the calculation of the Oriented cobordism groups in dimensions higher than 10? Or if anybody knew if there is another kind of torsion beside 2-torsion in them? (e.g. I know that $\Omega^5$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, is there a group with n-torsion with n distinct from 2?).
Thanx, 
Refferences are also appreciated....

Answer (score 6):

There is no torsion other than 2-primary torsion in the oriented bordism ring.  One has that after inverting 2, the oriented bordism ring is a polynomial algebra on generators in degrees which are multiples of 4:
$$
\Omega^{SO}_*[1/2] = \mathbb{Z}[1/2, x_4, x_8, x_{12}, \ldots]
$$
If I remember correctly, this (and the answers to many bordism-related questions) can be found in Stong's "Notes on cobordism theory".

Comment: Thanks, I looked up the reference and it was very helpful... I would still like to know, and sorry and if this is now redundant, if not having any but 2-primary torsion now implies all torsion being like $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or could you have $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ for $n \neq 1$?

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend Wall's [Determination of the cobordism ring](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970136) as a more primary source, it also contains the fact that all torsion is of order 2.